# Use string as a property in lambda expression c#

Tags: c#, lambda

I have a method which I pass string and a list in to. What I'm trying to achieve is to convert the string into lambda expression property.

```
private someMethod(string myTypeString, List<Values> typeList)
{
    foreach(var type in typeList.Where(x => x."myTypeString" > DateTime.Now))
    {
        //do my loop
    }
}
```

Is there a way to do that?

Comment: Via reflection.

Comment: Wh at you posted won't work.  You can't have x."myTypeString".  You could do something like this (x => DataTime.Parse(x.myTypeString) > DataTime.Now)

Comment: And why not redesign the method to receive a `Predicate<Values>`? You would not need reflection you would only need to send the expression you want to apply.

Comment: putting the first two comments together: it can be done via reflection, maybe you get help in the question linked to by @BojanB. But you should consider runtime behaviour if you have big lists to filter by your reflection-get-thing

Comment: This is not something you should be doing. It's a gigantic "code smell". One possible solution could be to send in a Func<Values,bool> to the method instead. Reflection should be avoided when possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try using *Reflection*:

```
using System.Reflection;
...

private void someMethod(string myTypeString, List<Values> typeList)
{
    PropertyInfo pi = typeof(Values)
      .GetProperty(myTypeString,
         System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Instance | 
         System.Reflection.BindingFlags.NonPublic | // private/internal/protected  
         System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Public);

    // property exists, can be read and returns DateTime
    if (null == pi)
      return; // or throw exception
    else if (!pi.CanRead)  
      return; // or throw exception 
    else if (pi.PropertyType != typeof(DateTime))
      return; // or throw exception

    foreach(var type in typeList
      .Where(x => (DateTime) (pi.GetValue(x, null)) > DateTime.Now))
    {
        //do my loop
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Create this method somewhere.

```
    public static object GetPropValue(object src, string propName)
    {
        return src.GetType().GetProperty(propName).GetValue(src, null);
    }
```

2. Use the method in your lambda expression

```
    private someMethod(string myTypeString, List typeList)
    {
        foreach(var type in typeList.Where(x => (DateTime)GetPropValue(x, myTypeString) > DateTime.Now))
        {
            //do my loop
        }
    }
```